# How to return from fabric def

Tags: python, fabric, os.system

```
def diffFile(path):
    firstFile=run("md5sum "+path)
    return firstFile
```

I want to execute the above method and get the return "firstFile" in calling method of python no success so far tried all possible manner. global is also not working to send the return to main call .. fabric create another process so any alternative ?

Answer (score 1):

Just use the subprocess module for calling external files.
There are several methods to handle the different output streams when calling external files.

```
def diffFile(path):
  return subprocess.check_output("md5sum "+path)
```